# Is there a sugar syntax for usings in CPP? Like using std::{name1, name2, ..., nameN}?

Tags: c++

Let's say I want to use

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
```

But I **don't** want to use

`using namespace std;`

Is there something like this:

`using std::{cout, cin, endl};`

I've tried

```
using std::{cout, cin, endl};
```

Instead I got a syntax error.

Comment: No, there is no such syntax.

Comment: You should just get used to writing `std::` like the majority of us. At first it seems like clutter, but quickly you can start to find comfort in knowing that a feature is standard, specially when less often used features start being introduced in a large code base.

Comment: Just use ``std::cout``, the extra few keystrokes are absolutely worth it.

Comment: typing the list of `using std::cout; using std::...` takes like 10 seconds, while the time required for thinking about the algorithm may take 10 hours, 10 days or more. In fact the typing cost is so negligible that good code bases never use `using std::cout` or similar, and always type the whole `std::` thing

Comment: `using std::cout, std::cin, std::endl;`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It doesn't "seem" like clutter, it *is* clutter. There are of course good reasons to explicitly qualify namespaces but just because of this let's not let lose sight of the fact that namespaces in C++ *do* introduce objective clutter which *does* have a concrete, negative impact on readability. And one of the concrete negative consequences of this is that namespaces in C++ are almost always flat (to keep the readability impact manageable), despite the fact that nested namespaces *could be* (and, in other languages, *are*) a valuable tool for organising APIs.

Comment: I'm listing items in namespace when writing test and need marchers from gmock and do not find this painful or annoying. `using testing::IsNull; ...` and when composing marchers dropping namespace is nice.

Comment: BTW what else you think you have to bring to global namespace by `using std::...`? Note there is Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL) which is nice and quite often makes `std::` not needed. For example `getline(std::cin, s)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of c++17, you can add multiple objects in `using` separated by a comma.

```
using std::vector, std::cout, std::cin;
```

Previously it required a separate `using` statement for each. See [the using declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) . You do have to include the full path for each declaration.